# When adding MapView to Android application, get cross-loader exception

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a project in Android and I want to add MapView to it.
I did the following:

1. Downloaded the Google APIs revision 3.
2. Added the maps.jar library to my project
3. Added the MapView to an activity
4. Created new Virtual Device with target the Google APIs (not the normal target Android 1.5)
5. Started the project

When I try to reach the activity with the map view, I get

> ....................
>
> 12-16 20:57:44.620:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(792): Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalAccessError:
>   cross-loader access from pre-verified
>   class
>
> 12-16 20:57:44.620:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(792):     at
>   dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(Native
>   Method)
>
> 12-16 20:57:44.620:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(792):     at
>   dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClass(DexFile.java:193)
>
> ............

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If using Eclipse, make sure that you don't have multiple references to the maps.jar on your Project Build Path. This includes any direct reference to the maps.jar, or implicit reference through the Google APIs Library (Google APIs [Android 1.5]). In fact, only having the Google APIs Library on your Project Build Path should be sufficient.

http://andmobidev.blogspot.com

Answer (score 0):

If using Maven's Android plug-in, make sure you declare the test project's dependency on the Application-Under-Test's APK to be in 'provided' scope, like the AUT's JAR:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-application</artifactId>
        <type>jar</type>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-application</artifactId>
        <type>apk</type>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>    <!-- ADD THIS -->
    </dependency>
```

The Maven examples (at the time of writing) all make the test APK depend on the application APK with default (i.e. 'compile') scope, causing any libraries that the application gives 'compile' scope to be packaged into the test APK too.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem today. My problem was that I added maps.jar to my project, instead of changing the Build Path to include `Google APIs [android-2.1-update1]` instead of the standard `android-2.1-update1`. Just including maps.jar in your project will throw an IllegalAccessException when `<uses-library>` is in the right place, and a `RuntimeException (stub)` when it's in the wrong place. The APIs have to be loaded through the Android API target.